# modal bootstrap

Tags: php, javascript, twitter-bootstrap

1º duvida: Eu consigo tratar variáveis em php + MySQL dentro da janela modal?

Estou tentando chamar um modal na minha pagina *index* e não esta funcionando, já procurei pela solução e também não consegui achar.

No inicio da página já tenho um `include` com o cabeçalho e dentro do cabeçalho já estou incluindo o arquivo Javascript do Bootstrap.

```
<!-- Seleciona os dados no mysql -->
<?php 
    $chamada = "SELECT id, produto, pedido, status from PEDIDO";
    $dados = mysqli_query($conexao, $chamada) or die(mysqli_error());
?>

<section class="news">
    <div class="page-reader">
        <h3>Lista de Pedidos <small>atualizado em <?= date("d/m/Y") ?></small></h3>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Produto</td>
            <td>Código do Pedido</td>
            <td>Situação</td>
            <td>Editar Pedido</td>

            <!-- Coloca os dados em um Array -->
            <?php 
                while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dados)) { 
            ?>
                </tr>
                    <td><?= $resultado['id']; ?></td>
                    <td><?= $resultado['produto']; ?></td>
                    <td><?= $resultado['pedido']; ?></td>
                    <td><?= $resultado['status']; ?></td>
                    <td><button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" 
                                data-target="#myModal">Confirmar</button> <button class="btn btn-danger">Cancelar</button></td>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
    </table>
</section>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tente colocar um botão que chamará seu modal, observe data-toogle=modal e data-target #myModal, o bootstrap cuidará do resto. `<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>`. Conforme a documentação: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: já tentei fazer isso porem a pagina não exibi nenhum resultado.
sera que o problema é com a inclusão do JS?
estou fazendo assim:
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: Você colocou conteúdo dentro da div modal-body? E que tipo de tratamento gostaria de fazer dentro do modal? Alterar valores, etc..? Você incluiu o jquery na sua página também?

Comment: O modal simplesmente não aparece, mesmo depois de colocar o data-target e o id com o mesm onome ele não aparece.
o jquery que inclui está assim:
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>

Eu quero alterar uma coluna de uma tabela do mysql dentro do modal.

Comment: Por que a inclusão 2x do jquery? Retire um... você adicionou ele antes do bootstrap? Carregue somente um js do bootstrap também, abra seu console (navegador) e veja se não está ocorrendo algum erro... pois deveria estar funcionando eu acredito. Vamos por partes, depois continuamos a parte da edição.

Comment: Consegui!
Acho que o problema é que eu estava chamando o CSS primeiro.
troquei de posição e funcionou perfeitamente! obg!

Comment: Agora a parte da edição, você vai ter que usar javascript (ajax), e enviar a requisição com as solicitações de edição para outra página... em fim dá uma olhada sobre ajax :)

Comment: @RafaelAcioly se possível, publique (como resposta) a solução, explicando como fez para resolver.

Comment: não entendi pode me dar um exemplo ? tipo esse http://jsfiddle.net/3okrLm05/?

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues o melhor seria você abrir uma nova pergunta. Coloque todos os códigos que usou e qual o resultado esperado (pode mencionar esse link que usou).

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft eu estava tentando ajudar e não com a dúvida.

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues Certo, desculpe, pelo "jeito" do seu comentário parecia uma dúvida.